# How to solve this quadratic congruence equation?

Tags: congruences

Well, we have :
$$n^2+n+2+5^{4n+1}\equiv0\pmod{13}$$
i'm little bit confused, I think i can solve this using the reminders of $n^2$, $n$ and $5^{4n+1}$ over $13$, by the way I have no idea about the Chinese Reminder Theorem no need to use it. and thanks in advance

#### edit:

$4 \le n \le 25$

Comment: Hint: calculate the values of $5^{4n+1}$ modulo $13$ for a couple of small values of $n$.  What do you notice?

Comment: I was trying to do that for each one $n^2$, $n$, and $5^{4n+1}$

Comment: What were the values you got for $5^{4n+1}$?

Comment: if i'm not wrong, $5,5,5,5,5,5,6,12,3,0,7...$

Comment: @Antaraz: That's only right up to the point where you start to get values different from $5$. Note that $5^2\equiv -1\pmod{13}$, and therefore ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm what do you mean ?

Comment: hmm, I'm using excel to do that

Comment: @Antaraz: Try using pencil and paper instead. You compute $5^{4n+1}$ by starting with $5$ and multiplying it by $5^4$ some number of times. What is $5^4\bmod 13$?

Comment: $5^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, right ?

Comment: @Antaraz: Yes. So since $5^{4n+1}=5\cdot (5^4)^n$ which is the same as $5\cdot 1^n$ when you work modulo 13 ...?

Comment: hmmm, interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to see that

$$5^2\equiv -1 \pmod{13}$$

So, we have

$$5^4\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$$

Therefore, for any n, we have

$$5^{4n+1}\equiv 5\pmod{13}$$

So, the equation simplifies to

$$n^2+n+7\equiv 0\pmod{13}$$

Considering vieta, we check the factors of 7,20,33,...
 Looking at the factors of 20 , we notice that 2 and 10 sum upto 12, which
 is $\equiv -1 \pmod{13}$, so 2 and 10 are the desired solutions.

Comment: That's okay, but could you explain more your last one, or i should use reminders for both $n^2$ and $n$ ?

Comment: I could post this answer only after passing a "human being test". Is this the new way to prevent spam ?

Comment: Of course, you can check the remainders in this case, because there are only 13 possibilities.

Comment: @Peter, that happens if you, say, copy-paste from elsewhere, SE believes that to be automated input, i. e,

Comment: I did not copy anything, perhaps it is because I did not post anything for a long time. Annoying, though.

Comment: It's still confusing what's the next step i should do i got the reminders of $n^2$ and $n$, but the sum should be $\equiv 6 \pmod{13}$ as i see...

Comment: Vieta says that the product of the solutions is equivalent to the constant of the quadratic equation (here 7), and the sum of the solutions is the negative of the linear coefficient (here 1). It has nothing to do with the sum of $n^2$ and n, which must, of course, be 6 here. Without Vieta, you simply calculate $n^2+n+7 mod 13$ and check for which n it is 0.

Comment: hmm, based on excel : the solutions are $4,12,17$

Comment: Or you solve $n^2+n=n(n+1)=6 mod 13$ by guessing the solution 2 (2*3=6) and observing that -3 is also a solution ((-3)*(-2)=6). This is another way to get the solutions.

Comment: What did you enter ?

Comment: By the way, the numbers 2 and 10 are the only solutions mod 13, but of course, 15 and 23 are also solutions, so in the range 4-25 we have the solutions 10,15 and 23.

Comment: Exactly I got it now $10,15$ and $23$, Thank you very much guys :p

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solutions]

I'm very sorry about this bad resolution i've used a webcam, i'm going to update it later on.